# Exporting frequency histogram result as CSV in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, csv, frequency-histogram

I have an image with 3 distinct value (0,1,2), and use the frequency histogram reducer to count frequency of each pixel value in certain geometry (sort of like a zonal statistic function).

I am trying to export the result of the frequency histogram to a CSV file, but it always returns an error saying "*Invalid argument: 'collection' must be a FeatureCollection.*"

Is there a way to convert the frequency histogram object into a feature collection? OR even better, any other straight forward method to export that simple table as CSV?

Here's snippet of my code:

```
 // COUNT EACH PIXEL VALUE FREQUENCY (ZONAL STATS)
var stats = primary2020.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e15
});

print(stats)

// EXPORT TABLE TO DRIVE
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: stats,
  description: 'PrimaryForest2020stats',
  fileFormat: 'CSV',
});
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/exporting#to-drive_1 See the second code snippet. You'll have to convert to feature with null geometry and then feature collection.

Comment: Thank you! So sorry that I missed that one on the tutorial. This solved it!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I missed one section on the GEE tutorial that specifically explains how to create a null geometry. This is the additional lines before the exporting process.

```
// Make a feature without geometry and set the properties to the dictionary of means.
var featurestats = ee.Feature(null, histo);

// Wrap the Feature in a FeatureCollection for export.
var stats = ee.FeatureCollection([featurestats]);

// EXPORT
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: stats,
  description: 'PrimaryForest2020Stats',
  fileFormat: 'CSV',
});
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you accept this as answer.