# Exporting frequency histogram result for *image collection* as CSV in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, csv, frequency-histogram

I am trying to export a feature collection of histogram data for an image collection as a table in GEE. The image collection has three bands, NDSI_Snow_Cover, NDVI, and "remapped," which contains counts for 0, 1, 2, null values. The final table would have four columns: [system:index, 0, 1, 2, null], where the values under the 0, 1, 2, and null correspond to the histogram values from the remapped band.

I used the following link to get the histogram info: [Exporting frequency histogram result as CSV in GEE?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/411127/exporting-frequency-histogram-result-as-csv-in-gee)

But because I have an image collection, when I try to add the information to an empty feature collection the result is an empty variable. Instead, I add it as a property using .set(), but then it is harder to work with it as a property. Do I need to declare my null feature collection outside of my .map function? Is there a better way to get it into a feature collection or to export this information?

```
 // COUNT EACH PIXEL VALUE FREQUENCY (ZONAL STATS)
var Hist_featureCollection = Collection.map(function(image){
  var stats = image.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e15})
  var image_Stats = image.set('pixelCount', stats) 
  var featurestats = ee.Feature(null, stats);
  var FeatStats = ee.FeatureCollection([featurestats]);
  return image_Stats // if i return FeatStats and export, the data table is empty
});

print(Hist_featureCollection)
// this is the right info but not as a feature collection
var pixelCountList = Hist_featureCollection.aggregate_array('pixelCount');
print(pixelCountList)

// Get a list of the dates.
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: Hist_featureCollection,
  folder: 'GEE',
  description:'pixelHist',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Comment: You're gettig pixelCount out of a FeatureCollection, why aren't you just exporting that collection?  You can select() which properties you want.

Answer (score 4):

You were really close of getting the desired output. The only changes you need to do is pass the `stats` dictionary as a named property for the `ee.Feature` without geometry. Additionally, you need to cast the list of Features obtained from the `map` to an `ee.FeatureCollection`. Finally, you might be interested in using the `selectors` argument to select the properties to export in `Export.table.toDrive`.

```
// COUNT EACH PIXEL VALUE FREQUENCY (ZONAL STATS)
var Hist_featureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection(Collection.map(function(image){
  var stats = image.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e15});
  //var image_Stats = image.set('pixelCount', stats) 
  var featurestats = ee.Feature(null, {'pixelCount': stats});
  //var FeatStats = ee.FeatureCollection([featurestats]);
  return featurestats; // if i return FeatStats and export, the data table is empty
}));

print(Hist_featureCollection);

// Get a list of the dates.
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: Hist_featureCollection,
  folder: 'GEE',
  description:'pixelHist',
  selectors: ['system:index','DATE_ACQUIRED', 'pixelCount'],
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```